# Break text into 256-character chunks

Tags: python

Hello I am very new to programming, the most I know is basic HTML.

I'm trying to section text into 256 character portions. From what I learned I should use

```
inFile = open('words.txt', 'r')
```

to open a text file

```
contents = inFile.read()
print(contents)
```

then I should use

```
str1 = file.read(256)
```

to group this text.

But I do not understand how to use these two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

Comment: Run a python shell, then look at `help(open)`, etc ... every function is documented. Don't worry if you don't understand it all, pick it up some at a time.

Comment: ok, but I'm so close! a user actually got me near to the end.

Answer (score 3):

The `.read` method reads a given number of bytes, or the entire file if no number is specified.  To split by characters rather than bytes, you should read the whole file and then chunk them up yourself.  Example:

```
# This is just a convenience so you don't have to worry about closing the file
with open('words.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    # Read the file
    contents = inFile.read()
    # This will store the different 256 character bits
    groups = []
    # while the contents contain something
    while contents:
        # Add the first 256 characters to the grouping
        groups.append(contents[:256])
        # Set the contents to everything after the first 256
        contents = contents[256:]
   print(groups)
```

Comment: could I see a video on how to apply this?

Comment: You should be able to copy / paste, and just change the `'words.txt'` part to your actual filename.

Comment: I don't understand, what is with the "while contest:" part and after it? including the # areas?

Comment: A while loop does whatever is in it while the condition is truthy.  In Python, a string is truthy until it's an empty string ("").  Above, it's basically saying "While the contents are a string, do this block", and the block keeps changing the contents to be smaller and smaller until it's an empty string.  The lines starting with a # are just comments, so they won't be executed as code, they are just there to help explain.

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: ^ when I used the first line it highlighted "infile"

Comment: I forgot a colon.  Edited to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using list comprehension

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    groups = [group for group in iter(lambda: inFile.read(256), '')]
```

**UPDATE**

If the `words.txt` contains non-ascii code and it is `utf-8` encoded.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('words.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') as inFile:
    groups = [group for group in iter(lambda: inFile.read(256), '')]
```

Comment: That is the ideal solution, but that will read 256 bytes at a time, and if the file has non-ascii characters it'll get funny.

Comment: Right. I didn't know that. I suggest just one of solutions.

Comment: @TimBrown I tested your code and it has same problem.

Comment: Your answer is better in terms of easy to read, easy to understand.

Comment: Because the result is in groups. `print groups` to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think people need to be more kind for those who are new to programming.

```
inFile = open('words.txt', 'r')
contents = inFile.read() #Read the file from HDD and Set the whole content to MEMORY.
```

Now `contents` has all characters in `words.txt`.

You can get first 256 characters like this.

```
str1 = contents[:256]    #Slice
```

You can get second 256 character like this.

```
str2 = contents[256:512] #Slice
```

Comment: though I don't see anything happening :/

Comment: @user3543478: Just try `print str1`.

Comment: your method works! I just need more thing. I can see str1 but how do I make str2 come up?

Comment: @user3543478: OK. Then try `print len(str1)` and `print len(str2)`. It print out length of the string.